# How to set custom rules like difficulty level for GameCenter to find match

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, game-center

Need to set dynamically some rules of game and inform possible players (while GC searches for players/automatch) about those rules before the player connects. Lets say I want to host/start a game and i want to set some starting amount of betting units (10...1000), level of difficulty(0...10), scoring system (0..3) etc. I imagine this like a table with cells providing this information so player decides if he/she wants to join and play game with such rules. How to implement it?
AFAIK GKMatch uses only min and max number of players while searches for players and thats all. I could provide such information in invite but I need it for other players who r looking for game by themselves, like browsing existing games including rules. My game doesn't allow to join players since game is started but I need somehow to fill needed amount of players for session. Like if I want to play with only one player I start a game with number of players=2 (and some custom rules) so I need the GC to help me to find opposite player. And that player should be informed about my rules set before joining me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 2 possibilities:

Use these properties of `GKMatchRequest`:

> `@property(nonatomic, assign) uint32_t playerAttributes`
>
> *A mask that specifies the role that the local player would like to
>   play in the game.*
>
> If this value is 0 (the default), this property is ignored.
>   If the value is nonzero, then automatching uses the value as a mask
>   that restricts the role the player can play in the group. Automatching
>   with player attributes follows two rules:
>
> A new player can only be added to the match if the bitwise AND of that
>   player’s mask and the mask of any player already in the match equals
>   0x00000000. Players are added to the match until the bitwise OR of the
>   masks of all the players in the match equals 0xFFFFFFFF. For more
>   information, see Game Kit Programming Guide.
>
> `@property(nonatomic, assign) NSUInteger playerGroup`
>
> *A number identifying a subset of players
>   allowed to join the match.*
>
> If your game sets the playerGroup property, only players whose
>   requests share the same playerGroup value are automatched by Game
>   Center. You can use any values you want for player groups. For
>   example, you could define different playerGroup values to implement
>   any of the following filters:
>
> A game could restrict players based on skill level. A game that
>   provides multiple games could use it to filter players into the
>   specific game they want to play. A game with multiple victory
>   conditions (for example, Capture-The-Flag, Survival) could match
>   players to others interested in the same rules. A game that provides
>   bonus content through in-app purchase could match players who own the
>   same content with each other.

This allows for some game configuration before searching for players.

For complex rules you need to send the configuration data after the match has been found and the players are connected (see GKMatch API). You need to use the reliable transmission mode here.

You could also combine these 2 ideas.